# OO Design, open/closed principle question

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, ooad, open-closed-principle

I've been thinking about this object oriented design question for a while now and have unable to come up with a satisfactory solution, so thought I'd throw it open to the crowds here for some opinions.

I have a *Game* class that represents a turn based board game, we can assume it's similar to Monopoly for the purposes of this question.
In my design I have a *Player* class containing a method *TakeTurn*.

The *Game* loops through all *Player*s and calls the TakeTurn method to do all the necessary things to complete the turn.
I want to be able to have n number of players, and be able to set an arbitrary number of them to be computer players.
So, my thought was to have a HumanPlayer class and a *ComputerPlayer* class, both of which derive from Player.

The *Game* knows only the *Player* class and simply calls the *TakeTurn* method on each *Player* in turn.
My problem comes in the fact that *ComputerPlayer* objects can be completely automated, i.e. keeping with the Monopoly example, can decide to buy a property using some piece of logic.
Now, with the *HumanPlayer* object, it needs to get an input from the actual user to be able to buy a property for instance, which seems to imply a different interface and potentially mean they shouldn't derive

I haven't been able to come up with a good solution to the problem without having the *Game* class know the actual implementations of the various *Player* classes explicitly.
I could always make the assumption in the *Game* class that there will only ever be human and computer players and effectively close it for extension, but it doesn't seem like good OO programming.

Any opinions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure the [tag:open-closed-principle] applies here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should not let the Game class handle IO.
this way, the (blocking) TakeTurn  method will hide from the game board the means of implementation. it can use other objects to communicate with the user.

All the Game class should concern itself with is the state of the board and the turn. the players should all implement a single Player interface, and hide all implementation from the Game.

Comment: +1 for striving to give Game good *cohesion* (proper responsibilities).

Answer (score 2):

If the Game is managing the game state **and** doing I/O, the Game is doing too much.

You want Game to be tightly focused on just rules and turns and state changes.
Game doesn't know what a player is; it only knows that it has players.

You want Players to examine the Game state and execute the legal actions during their turns.

Human Players and the Game as a whole *both* share a common I/O package that shows game state and prompts humans for their input.

You can make good use of the Java `Observable` by making the I/O package an `Observer` of the Game.  That way, Game state changes are reported to the I/O for display or logging or both.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably not have two `HumanPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer` classes, but a single `Player` class which is configured at creation time with the proper input strategy.

The way the player obtains information to decide its move in the next turn of the game is the *only* thing that varies (from the original problem description, at least), so just encapsulate that in a separate abstraction.

Whatever high-level class that sets up the game should also create the two sets of players (one human, another computer-simulated), with the proper input strategy for each, and then simply give these player objects to the game object. The Game class will then only call the `TakeTurn` method on the given list of players, for each new turn.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of telling the game class there is only ever one human, why not let it get that input during the menu/initialization of the game? If there are more players, that can be decided via some form of input (select players in the menu), prior to the game class initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The interface that *Player* presents to *Game* is orthogonal to the behaviour of derived *Player* classes.

The fact that the implementation of *TakeTurn* varies depending on the concrete type of the *Player* object should not be a cause for concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Game` Class should not concern about any implementations of the Player classes, and also ignore the User Interface.

Any user input needs to be handled by the `HumanPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

Im am not sure if this is what you want

```
public abstract class Player 
{
  int position;
  DecisionMaker decisionDependency;

  ...

  public void TakeTurn()
  {
    position += RollDice();
    GameOption option GetOptions(position);
    MakeDescion(option);
  }

  protected int RollDice()
  {
    //do something to get the movement
  }

  protected abstract void MakeDecision(GameOption option);

}

Public class ComputerPlayer : Player
{
  public ComputerPlayer()
  {
    decisionDependency = new AIDecisionMaker();
  }

  protected override void void MakeDecision(GameOption option)
  {
    decisionDependency.MakeDecision(option);
    //do stuff, probably delgate toan AI based dependency
  }
}

Public class HumanPlayer : Player
{
  public HumanPlayer()
  {
    decisionDependency = new UIDecisionMaker();
  }

  protected override void void MakeDecision(GameOption option)
  {
    decisionDependency.MakeDecision(option);
    //do stuff, probably interacting with the a UI or delgate to a dependency
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, the *Game* class shouldn't care if this is a computer player or a human player. It should always call *TakeTurn* on the next player class. If this is a human player, it is the responsibility of the *Player* class, to communicate with the user and ask the user what to do. That means it will block till the user made up his mind. As usually UI interaction takes place in the main thread of an application, it is only important that a blocking *TakeTurn* won't block the application as a whole, otherwise user input cannot be processed while *Game* waits for *TakeTurn*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the **Game** class calling ***TakeTurn*** on all the players the players should call ***TakeTurn*** on the **Game** class and the **Game** class should validate if the right player is taking his turn.

This should help solve the **User** and **Computer** player problem.